# Changing Jekyll's folder structure makes me lose custom layouts

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to setup a template Jekyll project with the structure below. The goal is to reuse all markdown files in the project while being the least intrusive, keeping all custom layouts and configurations in a single folder.

```
.
├── README.md          # some new project file stay in the roots
├── about.md           # some new project file stay in the roots
├── docs               # folder containing pages
│   └── assets
│   └── index.html     # generated from README.md
│   └── about.html     # generated from about.md
│   └── ...
├── jekyll              # folder containing all jekyll specific files
│   └── _layout
│   └── assets
│   └── _config.yml
│   └── ...
```

To make this work, I'm running Jekyll from the `/jekyll` folder using the following configurations.

```yaml
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman
source: ./..
destination: ./../docs
include:
  - "./_layout"
  - "./assets"
exclude:
  - "./"
```

Here comes my problem: when I do this Jekyll ignores my custom layout. Could anyone help me understanding this problem?

P.S.: I'd prefer not to publish my custom layout as a new theme entirely.

Comment: Do you have this in a public repository? It could help people wrap their heads around this if they could poke at it on their computer.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a public repository of it to share at the moment. I'll try to create such a repository later, however. Thank you for your input.